# Golang Illegal rune literal error when splitting string

Tags: string, go, rune

I am trying to split string based on split function in golang. But getting illegal rune literal error for r == '/--/' && r == '/-iN-/' && r == '/--/'

```
func Split(r rune) bool {
    return r == '/--/' && r == '/-iN-/' && r == '/--/'
}
```

Comment: no it didn't actaully. r == ':' or r == '.'     These are working without any errors. But my string literal is not

Comment: The point is rune works with single char like :  But i have multipe chars like /--/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, you can use single quotes for literal values that consist of a *single character*.

If you want to write a *string* literal, you should use double quotes or backticks :

```
'/'      // <- a single character
"/--/"   // <- a string
`/--/`   // <- also a string
```

You would also have to change your `Split` function because a `rune` cannot be compared to a string.

Comment: can i create a list of regex for splitting string ?